# Finding the roots of weighted sum of $\tanh$

Tags: calculus, roots

How can this equation be solved analytically? Is it possible, why? Is there a better alternative than the Newton approximation?

$k\tanh^2(ax+b) + l\tanh^2(cx+d) + m = 0 $ with $a,b,c,d,k,l,m \text{ constants } \in R $

Does an expression of $\tanh(ax+b)$ depending of $\tanh(x)$ exist?

Edit :

I found out that $\tanh(ax+b) = -\frac{(-(1 - \tanh(x))^a + \tanh(b) (1 - \tanh(x))^a + (1 + \tanh(x))^a + 
  \tanh(b) (1 + \tanh(x))^a}{-(1 - \tanh(x))^a + 
  \tanh(b) (1 - \tanh(x))^a - (1 + \tanh(x))^a - \tanh(b) (1 + \tanh(x))^a)
 }$

So if we pose $\tanh(x) = X$, the problem becomes :

$\frac{k(((1 - X)^a - e^{2 b} (1 + X)^a)^2}
{((1 - X)^a + e^{2 b} (1 + X)^a)^2}
+ \frac{l( ((1 - X)^c - e^{2 d} (1 + X)^c)^2}
{((1 - X)^c + e^{2 d} (1 + X)^c)^2}
 + m = 0$

Comment: This equation can probably not be solved analytically.  It might even be possible to deduce that from your new form by showing that it's equivalent to solving a (not nice) polynomial of high degree.

Comment: Are $a$ and $c$ integers?